# Which Java IO class is better to use for a simple shell interpreter?

Tags: java, shell, io, tokenize

I am new to Java IO library, so I have trouble choosing the right class for my purposes. I write a simple shell client for a file transferring server. My client should understand three commands: list files in a remote directory (optionally it can take a nested directory path as an argument), download a specified file (with a file path as the required argument) and end the session (a separate command). I am concerned with handling the user's input at the moment.
So the questions are:

1. Should I read the whole line of input, tokenize it and only then do some logic, or it is better to tokenize the input as it comes and make immediate decisions based on it?
2. What class should I use to tokenize the input: Scanner or StreamTokenizer? Or taking into account that my commands are much simple I could just use BufferedReader to read a line, then split the string by the `"\\s+"` pattern?

The questions may seem subjective in some way but I just want to diminish the confusion and understand the specific use cases of those IO classes.

Comment: You probably mean `"\\s+"` as the pattern for splitting the `String`.

Comment: @ChristianHujer, thank you. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Considering the commands are basic, reading whole input and then tokenizing will require a lot of efforts. It would be better to tokenize the input and then take decisions as required.
2. I think BufferedReader would be sufficient to serve your purpose here. It would make the code easy. Even when I was working on taking the input from a csv file and then tokenizing it to display as a graph I used the same. My logic for parsing the string goes below:-

   ```
     String splitBy = ";"; // As I am using CSV file below I used ";" as splitter. You can change as per your needs

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
     String line = br.readLine();
     while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
     {
          String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
          //Take actions you need to perform
     }
     br.close();
   ```

Hope this answers your question. Let me know if more details are required.